# Meld mergetool is not starting in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: git, diff, conflict, meld, mergetool

I want to resolve conflicts in my merge. I've set:

```
git mergetool -t meld
git config --global merge.tool meld
git config --global mergetool.meld.path /usr/bin/meld
```

separately and together, but they are not working for me.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 and meld version installed by apt-get install.

when I do:

```
git mergetool
```

I was wondering solve conflicts of merge using meld, but meld is not appearing, after hit return.

Comment: Do you have *any* merge conflict?

Comment: no, just meld is not starting, I set gitconfig and is not open as mergetool

Comment: For me, it was just taking 30 seconds to start the UI when I run `meld` directly, but I don't know why, some related posts: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=227431 | https://meld-list.gnome.narkive.com/HT2SAO3Z/very-slow-windows-startup

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue once, but for me there were conflicts on my git repo.

For me this helps:

- if `git mergetool` command hangs and not come up try to start `Meld` from the system itself (e.g. from launcher).
- it will start with a new empty diff, select *File->Exit*
- shortly after that `meld` will load with the git diff

Comment: but, I tried open meld by launcher, and it works, but when it is called by git mergetool, something happens..